# What software or programming language is good for a ticketing system or project management?

Tags: project-management, language, workflow, task-management

What software or programming language is good for a ticketing system or project management or task or workflow management. These are the requirements:

1- ***allow users to send an email to outlook 
via standard email address example ticket@help.com***

2- ***it will create a ticket after email and sends it to the 
parties that are configured to receive them.***

3- ***In addition all users can go to a link and view their 
ticket and see detail information regarding it.***

4- ***The ticketing system should have comments, and steps such 
as progress, done, pending, and closed etc.***

Is there a software out there that I can buy and how much is it or do I need to program it and what programming language is better to do this in and how long and difficult would it be to program it ?  How about MS sharepoint, would it do this ?  Thank you

Comment: Will this run on a mainframe? PC/MAC? Server? Web? Mobile device? Or a combination? The platform has more of an influence on the language you choose. However, the other school of though is you choose the software, then find the hardware to run this. Regardless, the question needs more details on how the user will use this system to determine both hardware and software. For example, is this for the returns department of a retail store or for a web hosting company where a customer needs help getting something to work?

Comment: PC, Server, and Mobile device.  It's for user who can send email via outlook from their company profile/account to a general ticketing email address and it post on the ticketing system. It will then send to the configure parties members of this ticket. User can send email from anywhere, phone, in another state as long as they are in the company network and has a ticketing system account credential.

Comment: Post your clarifications as edits to the Question rather than as Comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Request Tracker. It's a web based ticketing system with e-mail integration and custom workflow.
https://bestpractical.com/request-tracker/

Comment: Thank you for suggestion request tracker. It looks like it could be a very good ticketing system. I am going to check it out.

Comment: I think it can't use window operating system and db such as ms SQL server.

Comment: Anyone else have any more suggestions on a good web base ticketing system that can do the various task as I described ?

Answer (score 1):

### PHP/MySQL (and HTML)

Ticketing is a pretty common web feature you can get a lot of resources on. **PHP** is the go-to language for beginner web programmers, is widely supported and there is multiple tutorials. You will also have to learn basic **SQL** (and create a MySQL database) and **HTML5** for formatting web pages.

On the other hand, web development is not that hard but will take you a long time to learn for you to be able to build something like this properly.

### [osTicket](http://osticket.com/editions)

Built-in self-hosted ticketing solution: if you want to deploy your system fast at the cost of not having it personalized to your needs. You'll still have to tinker with web development and servers but the wiki/forums should provide you enough information.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am not an expert in PHP/ MySQL/ HTML and this may take a bit of time for me to code and implement. Nevertheless thank you for your great advise and suggestion.